# Как сделать select компонент в vue.js ?

Tags: vue.js

Я пытаюсь сделать select компонент, мне нужно сделать, чтобы при выборе вызывался метод из которого бы я смог получить выбранный пункт.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <select v-model="selectedItem" v-on:change="$emit('selected', selectedItem )">
        <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Selector',
    props: ['items'],
    data() {
      return{
        selectedItem: null
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Вот пример json с которым работает этот селектор.

```
[
  {"id":6,"name":"test group 6"},
  {"id":7,"name":"test group 7"},
  {"id":8,"name":"test group 8"}
]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы возвращался весь пункт JSON'a, то есть, например, так : `{"id":6,"name":"test group 6"}` ну или `id` , но у меня возвращается то что показывается, то есть так: `test group 6`, как я могу сделать, чтобы объект целиком возвращался, а не только его имя?

Answer (score 1):

нашел как это сделать, нужно было добавить атрибут `:value`

```
<template>
  <div>
      <select v-model="selectedItem" v-on:change="$emit('selected', selectedItem )">
        <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id" :value="item" >{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Selector',
    props: ['items'],
    data() {
      return{
        selectedItem: null
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```